# Elasticsearch Cluster can't see each other

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, autodiscovery

We have 2 Ubuntu machines on VMware hypervisor and those attached to the same virtual switch.
I installed same version of ElasticSearch (7.6) on them and you can find configurations right bellow:

node-1:

```
cluster.name: my_elk
node.name: node-1
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
transport.host: 192.168.30.14
network.host: [_local_,_site_,_global_]
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.30.15","192.168.30.14"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
```

node-2:

```
cluster.name: my_elk
node.name: node-2
path.data: /var/lib/elasticsearch
path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
transport.host: 192.168.30.15
network.host: [_local_,_site_,_global_]
discovery.seed_hosts: ["192.168.30.15","192.168.30.14"]
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
```

when starting them they work separately and both have a single active node, I have tried these configurations on one Linux machine with 2 containers and work correctly with the auto-discovery module.
What is wrong with my configuration?

Update: 
[log_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TMetCZVL9tejn8SAw73QkwirUzDbKy4D/view)

Comment: do you see any error in logs when they try to discover ?

Comment: @es-enthu how can I monitory discover logs?
I didn't find any discover log in my logs directory.

Comment: it will be printed in your elasticsearch startup logs only

Comment: using discovery type [zen] and seed hosts providers [settings]

Comment: can you provide the detailed log in your question?

Comment: path log is here: /var/log/elasticsearch

Comment: logfile attached

Comment: I think you should set node_1 node_2 IP's in /etc/hosts. VM's should ping each other trough node_1 and node_2

Comment: actually  one master is enough for two VMs

Comment: set master.node: false to one of the vms

Comment: @Amir, are you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja It fixed by clean cluster data path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two nodes are both working on their own then they have each formed a one-node cluster, which means that the first time they started up they were not configured as you have shown. You cannot merge these two one-node clusters into a two-node cluster. Instead, you should start again: wipe their data paths, and then they will form a brand-new two-node cluster.

There is a note at the bottom of [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html) of the reference manual that covers this problem:

> Elasticsearch will not merge separate clusters together after they have formed, even if you subsequently try and configure all the nodes into a single cluster. This is because there is no way to merge these separate clusters together without a risk of data loss. You can tell that you have formed separate clusters by checking the cluster UUID reported by GET / on each node. If you intended to form a single cluster then you should start again:

Answer (score 0):

For Elasticsearch cluster setup whenever we are starting Elasticsearch for the first time we have to add **cluster.initial_master_nodes** parameter in elasticsearch.yml and mention the master node in it.
example:-> cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["192.168.56.1:9300"]

Comment: The question already contains initial_master_nodes. How is your setting different? Just that 1 node mentioned, instead of 2?